# converting swift's "forced downcast(as!)" to objective c

Tags: objective-c, swift, struct

### I'd like to convert this swift line to Objective-C

```
let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (marker.userData as! location).lat, longitude: (marker.userData as! location).lon)
```

`userData` is of type id which is being forced downcast to `location` but when I try to cast the `userData` in Objective-C I get this:

> Multiple methods named 'location' found with mismatched result,
>   parameter type or attributes

This is my code:

```
struct CLLocationCoordinate2D markerLocation;
    markerLocation.longitude=[(CLLocation *)[marker.userData location] coordinate].longitude;
```

Comment: In Objective-C code you are calling a method ‘location’ on userData. You only have to typecast userData to your expected type. BTW what is the type of userData?

Comment: UserData is of type 'id'. Since location is a pointer to CLLocation i have cast it to CLLocaton but it doesn't work. Any way i wanna convert that swift line to Objective-C. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to cast `userData`, not the result of the `location` message.

```
markerLocation.longitude=[(CLLocation *)[marker.userData location] coordinate].longitude;
```

… should be …

```
markerLocation.longitude=[(CLLocation *)(marker.userData) coordinate].longitude;
```

Comment: Brilliant!! thanks a lot. It works perfectly. @Amin Negm-Awad